# My question got put on hold unfoundedly while three people agree that it is fine

Tags: support

[My question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/370197/107408) got put on hold for "asking others to name a variable", which it does not. You could argue that the question at first was borderline rule-breaking, but the thing is that I edited the whole question, so it now no longer even mentions programming and just asks for a hypernym and two hours LATER it got put on hold for the aforementioned reason.

Also in the comments (which have been moved to chat by the moderator [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52473/discussion-on-question-by-kim366-is-there-a-word-that-includes-encompasses-both)) three people mention that it is fine after a short debate of it breaking the rule before my large edit, after which the general consensis was that the question is fine.

Was the moderator right in this case? Did they not even read the question and just put it on hold because there were mentions of rule-breaking in the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm usually one of the more close-happy users on this site, but I think your question is fine.

It may have been originally inspired by your programming needs, but the way it's framed, it's not constrained to that context and any answers will be generally applicable.

I actually think it sets a good example of the *right way* to ask "how do I name this thing" on EL&U: by framing it as an English question which will be helpful to anyone who takes an interest in English!

<s>I'll go vote to re-open now.</s> Never mind, it looks like I had already voted to re-open. Someone else has, too. You only need 3 more votes. I suspect you'll get them as a result of this Meta-question.

<sub>All that said, since we're on Meta, let me offer a meta-answer to your question: I suspect there is no satisfactory word which can describe both a mouse button and keyboard key.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and clarification on how the 'on-hold' system works!

Comment: @kim366 Your question has now been re-opened.